# passport js, auth fail with http 500. no response

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm developing full-stack,

with
Node,
Express,
Session-mysql,
passport...

like a title, my router.post has no res.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    hasher({password: req.body.password, function(err, pass, salt, hash){
        var account = {
            authId: 'local:'+req.body.username,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: hash,
            salt: salt,
            displayName: req.body.displayName
        };
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO accounts SET ?';
        conn.query(sql, account, function(err, results) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("signup_post_in_error");
                res.status(500);

            } else {
                req.login(account, function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    req.session.save(function() {
                        res.redirect('/board');
                    })
                })
            }
        });
    }})
})
```

```
form(action='/signup' method='post')
```

when I click submit, there is no response.

Comment: send request to the '/' route, ```form(action='/' method='post')``` and update sending res to ```res.status(500).send('Something broke!')```

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi thanks. but only 404 page.